# How do I know if US lettuce is safe, given the E. coli outbreak?

Tags: food-safety, lettuce

I'm gonna order a turkey and swiss sandwich soon, on a spinach wrap.

Is it safe to get lettuce on it?

I know that in 16 states, over 50 people have gotten e.coli from lettuce, so I'm not sure whether I should get lettuce or not.

Comment: You should not sign your posts (the always-present username suffices), use all caps (shouting is not nice), or demand urgent answers (people will answer when they can).

Comment: Use iceberg instead of Romaine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CDC's current advice](https://www.cdc.gov/ecoli/2018/o157h7-04-18/index.html) as of April 20 2018 is quite simple:

> Do not buy or eat romaine lettuce at a grocery store or restaurant unless you can confirm it is not from the Yuma, Arizona, growing region.

So, by the CDC's definition of safety, it's not safe if it's romaine possibly from the Yuma area. It has nothing to do with where *you* are; things get shipped all around.